# Is Christmas not a christian festival

Tags: christmas

I have read many times that christ born around october so why do you people(christian) celebrate it as birth of christ you should stop celebrating it on 25 December and set a date in october.

> we know that the angels announced the birth of Christ to the Bethlehem shepherds in the open fields who were tending their flocks by night.. This fact certainly implies that the birth of Jesus could NOT have been on the 25th of December. "The cold of the night in Palestine between December and February is very piercing, and it was not customary for the shepherds of Judea to watch their flocks in the open fields later than about the end of October." Hislop, A., The Two Babylons, Loiseaux Brothers, Neptune, N.J. pg 91.

Comment: Has it not occurred to you that the assertion of October may be wrong? Anyway, an [official birthday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen's_Official_Birthday) is not that unusual.

Comment: @ Andrew Leach I am just asking isn't the official birthday should be in October

Comment: Related questions: [When did Christmas (the birth of Christ) first begin as a Christian celebration?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4772/21576) [On which date was Christ born?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1360/21576) [Why is Christmas on December 25th?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5144/21576)

Comment: @ Nathaniel my question is : shouldn't Christmas be celebrated on a date in october

Comment: @DhruvaMehrotra The answer is found in the last of those links.  There's long church tradition, and some biblical basis, for the December 25 date.

Comment: Just remember this.  Christmas is NOT a birthday party.  It is a feast day to celebrate the incarnation of the logos.  It is NOT a birthday!  It can be celebrated on any day but church fathers chose Dec. 25th for many of the reasons already addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is Christmas not a christian festival**

December 25th is very close to the winter solstice of December 21st. Our Christmas tradition is probably a combination of pagan solstice holidays, early Catholic church assignment of saints days, and the desire of northern Germanic tribes (for whom winter was much more arduous) to have a celebration for home and hearth.

This holiday had Christ woven into the fabric of various European cultures and now with American apostasy and advertising Christ is being taken out of our culture altogether including the Christmas holiday.

There is nothing Biblical about the date December 25th. It has come to have traditions of family, giving, and the birth of Christ associated with it. It has had and continues to some degree to have a strong sentimental association for family and home even as it is now often celebrated with a diminishing emphasis on Christ.

Comment: timf - FYI. Although the solstice is around 21 Dec, what is special about 25th is that is the date on which the sun appears to start to rise earlier in the morning. It was the official birthday of the sun god before Christianity took it over in the fourth century.

Comment: "It has come to have traditions of family, giving, and the birth of Christ associated with it."  That is not true for all cultures.  Christmas as you're describing it is primarily American.  A perversion and corruption of its intentions - IMHO

Answer (score 1):

For about the first three centuries after Christ's birth there were no estimates of the date. December 25th seems to be more about a Christian takeover of the Roman festival of Saturnalia, or the equally pagan festival of Sol Invictus, than any attempt to be historically accurate. The lambing season in the Judaen hill country is about mid-spring, with various early estimates putting Christs birth as 21st March, 20th April, or 20th May. All are doubtful dates. The fact is, we don't know. 
Not only is the date wrong, the year is also wrong. The Herodian dynasty is reasonably well fixed by historic dates, and the Herod who persecuted the infants in and around Bethlehem, died about 3 years before the conventional year zero. 
Bizarely, therefore, Christ was born approximately 3 1/2 or 4 1/2 years BC.